# How i retrieve data in iOS xCode SDK?

Tags: titanium, titanium-modules

I am using Titanium. and I want to make Titanium Module (for iOS).
every thing is working fine. But, how i retrieve data in xCode whose i send through .js file.

```
in .js file

var data = "Mritunjay";
var oldData = "Singh";
var data = module_tset.findData({"newData":data,"oldData":oldData});

in xCode 

-(id)findData:(NSMutableArray *)args
{
 NSMutableArray *ary = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:args];

// How i retrieve "newData" Value in xCode?

}
```

please help me..! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[First you should check the documentation for this.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/guide/iOS_Module_Development_Guide)

Also, [check the example moddevguide projects on GitHub](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/moddevguide/mobile/ios), they have very simple and straightforward examples of how to do this.

In a nutshell heres the code to extract those arguments (assuming you setup this correctly).

```
-(id)findData:(id)args
{
    ENSURE_SINGLE_ARG(args,NSDictionary); // Standard practice
    NSString *newData_Pass = [TiUtils stringValue:[args objectForKey:@"newData"]];  

    // Now do something with newData!

}
```

Thats it!

Comment: i replace this line "-(id)findData:(NSMutableArray *)args" instant with "-(id)findData:(id)args"